# convert REGEXP to LIKE in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have MYSQL query that looks as below

```
select * from table1 where host REGEXP 'host1';
```

I want to execute the same query using `LIKE`
Please suggest how it can be achieved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from table1 where host LIKE '%host1%';
```

`REGEXP 'host1'` will match `host1` anywhere in the string.  To phrase this using the `LIKE` operator we need to surround `host1` with wildcards.

Comment: @Phil Based on [this demo](http://rextester.com/PJHNS42111) it seems that your comment is mistaken.

Comment: Seems you are correct and reality differs to expectations

Answer (score 0):

You can try using %

```
select * from table1 where host LIKE '%host1%';
```